# How I can pass counter value to header of AlertController

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to actual pass value to header of alertcontroller. Alert shows up, but unfortunately header not show current this.counter value.

So here is my piece of code. Please note that function idleAlert(), is launched from the constructor.

```
private counter: number;


  startCountdown(seconds) {
    let counter = seconds;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter = this.counter;
        counter--;


        if (counter < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log('Ding!');
        }

    }, 1000);
}

async idleAlert() {
    this.startCountdown(100);

    this.alertIdle = await this.alertController.create({
        header: 'Current counter value is: ' + this.counter,
        cssClass: 'customAlert',
        backdropDismiss: false,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Logout',
                role: 'cancel',
                cssClass: 'alertBtnGrey',
                handler: (data) => {
                    this.stopWatching();
                    this.authService.logout();

                }
            }, {
                text: 'Contrinue',
                cssClass: 'alertBtnSuccess',
                handler: () => {
                    this.restartTimer();
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    await this.alertIdle.present();

}
```

Comment: Create a service where you can `get` and `set` the counter value as ` EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter().` In the header component subscribe to get that counter value. In other components constructor method, use `set` method to save the counter value and it should emit the value through`emit();` In every subseque change in the subscription value, the header component will get it

Comment: I did but doesn't work , take a look here https://pastebin.com/Rm763WSz

Comment: A shared service and a `BehaviorSubject` is one way to share data between components. Check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqxex9. Consider the "Total" as the alert header in your case.